# how to color a node of a graph using boost

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I was trying to create a graph using boost.I want to change the properties of node and edge.i'm getting compilation error.sorry for the duplicate question

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
struct my_graph_writer {
    void operator()(std::ostream& out) const {
        out << "graph [bgcolor=lightgrey]" << std::endl;
        out << "node [shape=circle color=blue]" << std::endl;
        out << "edge [color=red]" << std::endl;
    }
} myGraphWrite;
int main()
{
    using namespace boost;
    typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, no_property, int> Graph;
    Graph g;
    add_edge(0, 1, 123, g);
    std::ofstream gout;
    gout.open("graphname.dot");
    write_graphviz(gout,g,my_graph_writer);
}
```

I corrected as following.but fist node isn't changing .what is the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
using namespace boost;

typedef adjacency_list< listS, vecS, directedS > digraph;

//  define a property writer to color the edges as required
class color_writer {
public:
      // constructor - needs reference to graph we are coloring
    color_writer( digraph& g ) : myGraph( g ) {}
      // functor that does the coloring

    template <class VertexOrEdge>
    void operator()(std::ostream& out, const VertexOrEdge& e) const {

        out << "graph [bgcolor=lightgrey]" << std::endl;
        out << "node [shape=Mrect color=blue]" << std::endl;
        out << "edge [color=red]" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    digraph& myGraph;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    // instantiate a digraph object with 8 vertices
    digraph g;

    // add some edges
    add_edge(0, 1, g);
    add_edge(1, 5, g);
    add_edge(5, 6, g);
    add_edge(2, 3, g);
    add_edge(2, 4, g);
    boost::write_graphviz(f, g,color_writer( g ));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/write-graphviz.html), the `write_graphviz` overload with three parameters expects that its third parameter be a `VertexPropertyWriter`, so you need to use (as you were originally) the five parameter overload. This was your approach:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
using std::map;
struct my_node_writer {
    // my_node_writer() {}
    my_node_writer(Map& g_) : g (g_) {};
    template <class Vertex>
    void operator()(std::ostream& out, Vertex v) {
        out << " [label=\"" << v << "\"]" << std::endl;
    };
    Map g;
};

struct my_edge_writer {
    my_edge_writer(Map& g_) : g (g_) {};
    template <class Edge>
    void operator()(std::ostream& out, Edge e) {

        out << " [color=purple]" << std::endl;
        out << " [label=\"" << e  <<":" << g[e].miles << "\"]" << std::endl;
    };
    Map g;
};

struct my_graph_writer {
    void operator()(std::ostream& out) const {
        out << "graph [bgcolor=lightgrey]" << std::endl;
        out << "node [shape=circle color=blue]" << std::endl;

        out << "edge [color=red]" << std::endl;
    }
} myGraphWrite;

int main()
{
    using namespace boost;
    typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, no_property, int> Graph;
    Graph g;
    add_edge(0, 1, 123, g);
    std::ofstream gout;
    gout.open("graphname.dot");
    write_graphviz(gout,map,my_node_writer(map),my_edge_writer(map),myGraphWrite);

}
```

You have two problems: you can't use `g[e].miles` with your graph as defined and `Map` does not refer to anything.

In order to solve the first problem you need to create a struct with a member_variable named `miles` and use it as your `EdgeProperty` in your graph definition.
The easiest way to solve the `Map` problem is probably to make it a template parameter of the structs where it is needed (although you could also define your graph before your property writers and then use `Graph` instead of `Map`. This is the code after making those changes:

[**Running on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3d05645a3fda8e2):

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
using std::map;

template <typename Map>
struct my_node_writer {
    // my_node_writer() {}
    my_node_writer(Map& g_) : g (g_) {};
    template <class Vertex>
    void operator()(std::ostream& out, Vertex v) {
        out << " [label=\"" << v << "\"]" << std::endl;
    };
    Map g;
};

template <typename Map>
my_node_writer<Map> node_writer(Map& map) { return my_node_writer<Map>(map); }

template <typename Map>
struct my_edge_writer {
    my_edge_writer(Map& g_) : g (g_) {};
    template <class Edge>
    void operator()(std::ostream& out, Edge e) {

        out << " [color=purple]" << std::endl;
        out << " [label=\"" << e  <<":" << g[e].miles << "\"]" << std::endl;
    };
    Map g;
};

template <typename Map>
my_edge_writer<Map> edge_writer(Map& map) { return my_edge_writer<Map>(map); }

struct my_graph_writer {
    void operator()(std::ostream& out) const {
        out << "graph [bgcolor=lightgrey]" << std::endl;
        out << "node [shape=circle color=blue]" << std::endl;

        out << "edge [color=red]" << std::endl;
    }
} myGraphWrite;

struct edge_prop
{
    int miles;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace boost;
    typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, no_property, edge_prop> Graph;
    Graph g;
    add_edge(0, 1, edge_prop{123}, g);

    write_graphviz(std::cout,g,node_writer(g),edge_writer(g),myGraphWrite);

}
```

Comment: I corrected as above.but fist node isn't changing .what is the problem?

Comment: also how to change the color of vertex which is visited